# TAX/VAT is required

Tags: magento2, customer, validation, registration

I'm not sure how this is possible so i hope one of you know

I have a multi website Magento 2 setup with 1 website that requires VAT and the other doesn't.

I disabled the VAT on customer registration trough the configuration for 1 website :

[image]

Now it doesn't how during customer registration but after submitting i get this error :

[image]

Not sure what is wrong

Hoping someone can help

Comment: I noticed that in the backend its also still required?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in core Magento, a workaround would be to turn off Eav cache. 
This issue should have been fixed in 2.2 but appears to not have been completely fixed. I'm opening a ticket on their github to get it fixed.

Comment: can you link to github so i can back you up?

Comment: @René Schep Is this the mentioned github issue? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10978

Comment: I have just build a fix module for now